# Website showing the old front page even after deleted

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, cpanel, bluehost

I have a [webpage](http://carlbalita.org) that has some problems.
Recently I needed to update some content on my website and realized that my front page of the website is static and non-replaceable.

I know this because I have tried deleting this current page in WordPress and replaced it with the new one in the Dashboard, and it's still showing the same page that I have permanently deleted from the Pages section in the WP Dashboard.

I even tried to use SeedProd's Maintenance option to temporarily disable the homepage, and yet it is still showing.

Is there a way to replace this static page or simply get rid of it?

Note: I thought it would be Cloudflare's caching, but it's highly unlikely because I can see my newly made website changes everywhere except for the homepage.

I use Jevelin theme with its outdated Unyson theme.

Looking forward to your replies. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the homepage is being cached. You can inspect the response headers in the browser developer tools when visiting your homepage, here is what I see when I tried:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=691200, must-revalidate
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
```

`691200` is 8 days so this might explain why you see old content. A `HIT` value for `CF-Cache-Status` indicates that the content is being served from the Cloudflare cache (at least when I attempted from my location).

Worth checking if you have any Cloudflare Page Rules configured to cache the homepage, or if your origin server is setting the `Cache-Control` header to that value.

More information:

- [Understanding Cloudflare's CDN](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Understanding-Cloudflare-s-CDN)